# AWS S3 "Access denied"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-denied, multer-s3

I am using Node.js and multer3s to communicate with AWS S3. I have tried a few different setups but still cannot make it right to actually upload a file to my bucket.

For the S3 setup I have followed [this](https://medium.com/@imranhsayed/how-to-create-a-user-and-bucket-amazon-web-services-aws-40631416e65) tutorial.

In my IAM service I have a user `myuser` that has this

#### **permission policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

then I have a bucket that has set `Block all public access` to `off` (I have also tried to have it on).

The bucket has:

- **bucket policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddCannedAcl",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::228522121793:user/myuser"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "public-read"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

- **CORS configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

- under `Access points` sections there are no access points created.

#### in Node.js

```js
aws.config.update({
    accessId: ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: SECRET_KEY,
    region: 'eu-west-3'
})

const s3 = new aws.S3()

const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: BUCKET,
        acl: 'public-read',
        key(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, Date.now() + shortid.generate())
        }
    }),
    limits: {
        files: 1,
        fileSize: 2580 * 1944
    },
    fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        // filter
        cb(undefined, true)
    }
})

router.post('/test/img', upload.single('img'), async (req, res) => {
    console.log("success")
    console.log(req.file.location)
    res.send()
}, (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({
        error: error.message
    })
})
```

I would appreciate any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the error message you get?

Comment: @tkwargs the error message is only "Access denied" if you mean the error from the router.post

Comment: When the Nodejs SDK is attempting to upload the file to S3, but doesn't have the proper permissions, you should see in your server/lambda logs the error message from AWS stating what S3 action you attempted and that you don't have the permissions.

Comment: @tkwargs oh, ok. I don't se anything like that. I run nodemon and the only think that gets print out is "Access denied" because of my print statement. And I don't have any image uploaded in the bucket

Comment: Are you able to add more verbose logging?